# Ionic input is obscured by navigation bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a long input list in one page. When I move the focus to next input through KeyboardAccessoryBar, the focused input can be obscured by navigation bar sometimes.

I have posted this issue on IONIC forum, but have not gotten a solution.

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-input-is-obscured-by-navigation-bar/35466

**repro step:**

1. create a long input list:

   click the **next** button on KeyboardAccessoryBar to make focus move to next input.

[image]

2. Everything is OK till now, when the input NO. is 4.

[image]

3. OK, let's go on. click the **next** again, and try to move focus to the 5th input. issue occur, the 5th input is obscured by navigation bar.

[image]

**MY findings:**

1. This issue is easy to reproduce on IOS 9. (It's not easy to reproduce on ios 7.1.2)
2. If I remove ionic keyboard plugin from the project, the issue can not be reproduced.

**Test code:**

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->
        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-view>
                <ion-pane>
                    <ion-content class="has-header">
                        <form>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">1</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">2</span>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="test"  >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">3</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">4</span>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">5</span>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">6</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">7</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">8</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">9</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">10</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">11</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">12</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-pane>
            </ion-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Any God can help me out? Thanks very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code, It worked for me 
Remove `<ion-view></ion-view>, <ion-pane></ion-pane>` tags

```
<body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        </ion-nav-bar>
                    <ion-content class="has-header">
                        <form>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">1</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">2</span>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="test"  >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">3</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">4</span>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">5</span>
                                <input type="number" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">6</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">7</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">8</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test" >
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">9</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">10</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">11</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                            <label class="item item-input">
                                <span class="input-label">12</span>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </ion-content>

    </body>
```

Comment: I have tried on real device (Iphone5 ios 9.1), your solution can not work. In addition, ion-view can not be removed, it is the basic view for navigating in IONIC.